# Make array part of input directly

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to write my own vector. I have to initialize an array first, then set the value of the vector to the array (block 2). How do I combine these two steps (block 3)?

```
template <class T>
class Test{
public:
    T value

    Test operator= (T list[]){
      ...//value = list[2]
      ...
      ...
      ...//do stuff to make array
      return 0;
    }
}
```

```
int main() {
  int testarr[] = {0, 12, 23};
  Test<int> vect = testarr;
  std::cout << vect.get(2) << '\n';
}
```

```
int main() {
  Test<int> vect = {0, 12, 23};
  std::cout << vect.get(2) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make initializer for class with 'initializer_list' parameter.

```
Test(const std::initializer_list<T>& Initializer);
```

Then you need to implement it

```
Test<T>::Test(const std::initializer_list<T> &Initializer)
{
    //InnerArray = new T[Initializer.size()];
    
    int i = 0;
    // There is no indexer for initializer_list
    for (T Elem : Initializer)
    {
        InnerArray[i] = Elem;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

After then it will be possible to do something like that

```
Test<int> vector1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Test<int> vector2({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

[Check more details here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Answer (score 1):

Define a constructor that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as a parameter.

You also need to implement the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Try something like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Test{
private:
    T *value = nullptr;
    size_t count = 0;

public:
    Test() = default;

    Test(const Test &src)
    {
        value = new T[src.count];
        std::copy_n(src.value, src.count, value);
        count = src.count;
    }

    Test(Test &&src)
    {
        value = src.value; src.value = nullptr;
        count = src.count; src.count = 0;
    }

    Test(std::initializer_list<T> list)
    {
        value = new T[list.size()];
        std::copy_n(list.begin(), list.size(), value);
        count = list.size();
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        delete[] value;
    }

    Test& operator=(T rhs)
    {
        std::swap(value, rhs.value);
        std::swap(count, rhs.count);
        return *this;
    }

    T& get(size_t index)
    {
        return value[index];
    }
};
```